# Лексические нормы

Tags: лексика

Почему сочетание "где-то  в конце дня" является ошибочным?

Comment: А кто сказал, что оно ошибочно? =)

Comment: Пособие :)
Думаю, слово "где-то" стоит заменить на "приблизительно".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Сочетания *более-менее важный, где-то в конце дня, спелёнатый малыш* являются разговорными. Сочетания *более или менее важный, примерно в конце дня* общеупотребимы.](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_265645)

Полностью согласен. Думаю, что проблема в том, что словосочетание в целом отвечает на вопрос "*когда?*", т.е. время, и употребление слова "*где-то*", указывающего на место, как-то странно.